# Script by using paramiko and threading modules - multiple commands in single ssh session -ISSUE

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

I'm developing a script by using paramiko and threading modules in python. I want to execute multiple commands in a single ssh session. The reason for this is, if the session gets disconnected after the execution of the first command the old configuration (Commands) will not save, so i have to re-do from first.

My question here is, is there a way we can simplify this code?

```
import threading
import paramiko
class AllowAnythingPolicy(paramiko.MissingHostKeyPolicy):
    def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        return
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AllowAnythingPolicy())
client.connect('10.3.4.2', username='admin', password='g@defsl')  # password='')
def read_until_EOF(fileobj):
    s = fileobj.readline()
    while s:
        print (s.strip())
        s = fileobj.readline()
out1 = client.exec_command('alicreate "fesxa_p1", "10:00:00:00:00:00:00:80"')[1]
out2 = client.exec_command('zonecreate "fesxa", "fesxa_p1;"')[1]
out3 = client.exec_command('cfgsave')[1]
out4 = client.exec_command('yes')[1]
out5 = client.exec_command('cfgenable "active_config1"')[1]
out6 = client.exec_command('yes')[1]
out7 = client.exec_command('exit')[1]
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=read_until_EOF, args=(out1,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=read_until_EOF, args=(out2,))
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=read_until_EOF, args=(out3,))
thread4 = threading.Thread(target=read_until_EOF, args=(out4,))
thread5 = threading.Thread(target=read_until_EOF, args=(out4,))
thread6 = threading.Thread(target=read_until_EOF, args=(out4,))
thread7 = threading.Thread(target=read_until_EOF, args=(out4,))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
thread4.start()
thread5.start()
thread6.start()
thread7.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()
thread4.join()
thread5.join()
thread6.join()
thread7.join()
print (threading.Thread)
client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that threading isn't really the right approach here. Threading is generally for when you want to run things concurrently, and often the things that running may or may not complete in the order they started for a variety of reasons.
Since you're applying configuration to a device, and order matters, threading is really not appropriate. You should probably just use Paramiko and run the command sequentially and check the status of the session after each command, or even consider using something like pexpect.